# Errors building AzureToDo.Mac sample app

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

Downloaded the AzureToDo.Mac sample to learn how to get a MAC app working with Azure. (I have completed a Xamarin.Forms PCL app and have all device types successfully accessing Azure.) I have then tried to learn how to get the same app working for MAC by first trying the sample app.

I get the errors "The type or namespace 'iMobileServiceTable' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference. and The type or namespace 'MobileServiceClient' could not be found..." in the TodoItemManager class.
I am on the latest version of Xamarin Studio Community ver 6.1.1 for Mac. macOS Sierra ver 10.2.1.

I have updated all microsoft packages such as BCL, and BCL.Build and Azure.Mobile.Client and Newtonsoft.Json. but no success.

I notice that under References only Newtonsoft (FromPackages) and Microsoft CSharp, System, System.Core, System.Net.Http and Xamarin.Mac are the only items. But under Packages I have Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client, the packages for the items under References and heaps of other System packages.

When you right click and select Edit References, none of the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client methods are exposed for selecting.

Can you let me know what I need to do to get the sample app working.  This is my first app on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps doesn't support Mac as a platform.  There is no .Ext platform specific code available in the SDK for the Mac.

The main reason for this is because the login code has not been written for Mac.

Comment: Thanks for your response Adrian, I also entered this on Xamarin forums where Xamarin have passed it on to Craig Dunn the author of the app.  I already presumed that what you said would be the answer.

Comment: Answer from @CraigDunn Xamarin The "good" news is that Xamarin.Mac can also (pretty close to) behave as a plain old .NET 4.5 implementation, so by manually referencing the /packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.0.3/lib/net45 I was able to get it working again.

I made two minor changes:
•the Azure portal no longer uses a key - so I deleted that from the MobileServiceClient constructor
•the default TodoItem doesn't seem to contain a notes field any more, so I commented that out for my test (but you could easily add the column and field back manually)

Updated project is on GitHub.